# Why the edges of UIView are not smooth for huge corner radius?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

```
class AttributedView: UIView {
    private let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 3 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

I simply use it for both: button view (corner radius: 20) and background circle (corner radius: 600).

Why button is smooth, and background is not?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iOS 13.0 you can simple do, in addition to setting corner radius

```
yourView.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
```

Answer (score 1):

UIBezierPath is a simple and efficient class for drawing shapes using Swift, which you can then put into CAShapeLayer, SKShapeNode, or other places. It comes with various shapes built in, so you can write code like this to create a rounded rectangle or a circle:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 256, height: 256)
let roundedRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 50)
let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
```

You can also create custom shapes by moving a pen to a starting position then adding lines:

```
let freeform = UIBezierPath()
freeform.move(to: .zero)
freeform.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
freeform.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 150))
freeform.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 50))
freeform.addLine(to: .zero)
```

If your end result needs a CGPath, you can get one by accessing the cgPath property of your UIBezierPath.

Answer (score 0):

You should use bezzier paths and draw circle. After that you will receive nice, smooth edges.

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor] as CFArray, locations: [0, 1])!
let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 64, y: 9, width: 111, height: 93))
context.saveGState()
ovalPath.addClip()
context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: CGPoint(x: 119.5, y: 9), end: CGPoint(x: 119.5, y: 102), options: [])
context.restoreGState()
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably should clip bounds of this view:

```
attributedView.clipsToBounds = true
```